Users should not allege close voters are mindless or malicious or otherwise not acting in good faith
It is unkind to allege that close voters are casting their votes in a mindless manner, or acting out of malice, as opposed to from a good faith belief in the reason for their close vote.
Users should not make such allegations.
Such allegations are counter to the expectation in the code of conduct of a community of "kindness, cooperation and mutual respect."

I agree that this is a good standard for all users. I also think that moderators should hold themselves to an even higher standard.

I agree with the principle, but it implies that (1) users properly understand the way the system works, and (2) bad faith close votes never happen. Both implications seem (shall we say) a tad idealistic.

There have been posters here who express the desire for the site to have no questions about Gods, theism, or any non-physicalist ontology, as well as not have any posts questioning physicalism.  There is also a much higher rate of closure for such questions.  The inference that the posters who expressed such a desire, might then act upon it, strikes me as a reasonable inference.  The very close correlation between this inference, and what has been happening on this board -- leads to a conclusion that bad faith close votes are likely happening.

@Dcleve Yes, but with a mere five votes, we can beat back the authoritarians, ideologues, and bad actors! For five years, I have been advocating a caucus. We should build a simple website outside the PhilSE jurisdiction, and wield democratic power for the betterment of the establishment. ; ) Just send up the bat signal, and we can enforce Commissioner Lowri's vision of a fair and just Gotham. But alas, too many libertarian wills and an oppressive capitalist system makes it tough to wrangle the effort. : (

@Syed I think the discussion tag essentially frees the OP from having to provide an actual question in practice.

@TedWrigley "Both implications seem (shall we say) a tad idealistic." But then you could only say something like "Did you know that some close voters make mistakes, maybe even on purpose? The decision to close this post might or might not be such a case." Wouldn't sound nearly as impressive. We still can't say anything reliable about specific people or specific incidents.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: it's called 'contextual awareness'. There is no substitute for thinking.

@Dcleve: I hope I'm not included in that (I hate this keyboard) "some users". I have never said that discussion of philosophy of religion doesn't belong here, I only questioned whether I belonged here when that, at the time, appeared to be a major focus. I think it's clear that I was jumping to conclusions, and I believe I already apologized for that... But if that is something I will police myself on rather than expecting the community to change.

@keshlam  Not all physicalists are intolerant of theism, philosophy of religion, dualism, and non-physicalism on this board.  I am glad you are not.  One learns from dialog from those with different POVs, and most of the philosophic insights I have achieved have come by engaging the thoughts of philosophers I disagree with on one or many issues.  I hope others learn from engaging with mine.

In this case it would be both sufficient and adequate to instead say
"Also I would like to emphasize that the given user has received a lot of close votes recently for questions that are at least bordering the acceptable and similar to other questions that are not closed, and I would like to encourage voters to avoid the impression of targeting individual users, e.g. by abstaining from serial voting in the same user, and relying on other readers opinions to spread out the democratic process for deciding on appropriate content".
(Or something more eloquent in the same vein)
The accusation that any single voter voted out of bad faith can only be justified when any comment is given to that extent.

I was clear several times that no individual is named, and that there may be a mix of good-faith and bad-faith votes on a single question.

The problem is that repeat offenders cry "discrimination" when they keep making the same or similar offense over and over.

@IdiosyncraticSoul Are you suggesting that "repeat offenders" only arise in the questioner/answerer set but not in the VTC-er set?

@causative that means if those alleged bad faith voters were out of the picture, the same questions might still get closed by enough innocent voters. Just a little later. It's unclear what solution you propose, do you want to have such a meta thread and drama every couple of days?

Now hold on, you're saying this is against policy because it is an "unkind" (negative) allegation against a user or group of users - regardless of whether it is true? So to be consistent you would have to also assert that any negative allegations against any users or groups of users also should not be made, regardless of topic and whether these allegations are true? Please make clear your position about that.
There have been several posts saying negative things about some users recently. Is it your position that all such posts should be deleted simply because they are negative, even the ones that are accurate?
The Code of Conduct lists:

Bullying and Harassment - severe, repeated, or persistent unsolicited conduct, misuse of power or tools, or attacks that target specific users or groups of people in a manner that causes harm.

(emphasis mine). So misuse of close votes to harass a particular user would fall under bullying and harassment. It seems to me that raising and discussing problems like this in the community is what Meta is for.
Although I do agree that we should not name specific users publicly, as that can cause its own kind of harm. But saying that there is a problem by an unspecified/unnamed group of users harassing a particular user through close votes, does seem like the kind of thing Meta is for, provided there is enough evidence this is happening.
The nature of close votes is such that we usually can't say why any particular user voted the way they did. There may be bad-faith and good-faith close votes on the same question. But if several users consistently vote in a discriminatory way against a user, closing questions with insufficient or no legitimate reason while similar questions by other users remain open, this pattern can be seen.

Statistics can only show numeric properties of behavior, not motive. Public claims without proof are putting every behavior into question. The standard for saying something negative should be what can be proven, and statistics do not prove intent. If they could, then banning users for violating harassment rules would be in order. If your claims are not strong enough to ban any user who ever voted to close any question of Syed, you should also not make assertions about what motivated the close votes in your opinion. Simply not naming users is insufficient when their names can be inferred.

"while similar questions by other users remain open" there is no rule that close voters have to be strict and consistent. Just because i downvote once does not mean i have to spend the rest of my life policing similar questions. Leaving some bad questions open does not justify leaving all bad questions open. Or else the accusations should be that a group of users is not closing enough similar questions.

In the American legal system, juries are deciders of facts. Higher courts can issue judgements on the legal process - is a particular law constitutional, were a defendant's rights respected, etc.. Higher courts reversing a jury's finding of fact is a sign of corruption. The fact that we now have here a moderator issuing personal decisions on the factual question "some specific question is or is not suitable for the site" looks quite bad to me.

Rushi, calm down; no one is accused of murder - no specific person is accused of anything. @JonathanZ, the most recent question related to this was reopened by votes, none of which were mine, not moderator action. However, deciding which questions are suitable for the site is part of the role of moderators; I have been choosing not to exercise it in this case, in favor of a more open and democratic process.

@causative - If the more open democratic process had not resulted in a re-opening, do you think you would have exercised your moderator powers to ensure the outcome you prefer? Because the way I understand moderator powers (which could easily be inaccurate), you have greater powers, but should use them more sparingly. I would expect that in a given situation you would decide whether or not moderator intervention is called for. If you decide "yes", then you act immediately. If you decide "no, not here", you let the community act and let their decision stand. Is this the accepted standard?

@JonathanZ In the cases I've brought attention to, I did decide "yes," but did not act immediately because I also have some respect for a majority vote and do not wish to overturn it unilaterally although I disagree with it. Also it may have been that other moderators have different views and I don't want to step on their toes either. By instead inviting others to reopen, I build consensus and awareness around the problem. Had others not voted to reopen after I invited them to, I would not have done so unilaterally in those cases.

So you decided "yes, moderator intervention is called for, but not to the extent of unilaterally opening/closing"?

It would be nice to suggest a reopening vote without playing the pity card suggesting every reopen voter is a hero against harassment. That muddies the water about whether any reopen vote is based on content versus based on group dynamics.

@MisterMiyagi The point is that we can say that a user is being harassed and take steps to defend them without needing to say by whom.

@MisterMiyagi The action regular users can take is to vote to reopen these questions that were closed. Of course, it would be wrong to start throwing names around.

Why not? There is no rule against it and if it’s plainly obvious that certain users are being targeted, it should be pointed out. You can disagree with it sure, but that’s not a valid reason to allow someone to express that opinion.
Secondly, where is the question here? There is no question in this post and it is merely an opinion. All you’re doing is using this meta for something that is not meant for its use. Again. Where is the  question in this post?
Your complaint is all the more ironic since your “question” per the rules of this site should be closed

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta meta is a bit different

@Kaia where does it say one can rant about random things without asking an actual question?

Yes, ma'am! I see you take both rule of law and the spirit of comity seriously. Your esprit de corps encourages us all to remember our obligations to the community. Keep up the moral and ethical exhortations!

I'm mostly not being ironic, here, but absurdism entreats some measure of playful impishness.


It is unkind to allege that close voters are casting their votes in a mindless manner, or acting out of malice

Yeah great. Except when that happens. Let me tell you about "unkind."
In early 1900s, judges were very serious and technical when you did something bad. But if a white man did something bad to a black person, suddenly it was good old boy, wink-wink, everybody knows what's really going on but we don't talk about it.
GOD KNOWS: I'm not the best judge of other people's intentions. But I think I've seen that happen here, to me, in the physics and astronomy stax. In one case, when I tracked down the people who voted to close and asked them why, NONE even tried to come up with a coherent reason. @starship (who I foolishly used to trust) said, "I'm not going to comment on that. Others have pointed out to you what's wrong with your question."
In fact, no one had.
IRL this used to happen because my coworkers didn't see that things they struggled to understand were actually simple. Then they got mad, like it was my fault. Same happened when I accidentally used "big words" around the normals.
Once, I was about to say "exigent," but I said "contingent" instead, specifically so I wouldn't intimidate the secretary. But apparently "contingent" is a big word, too. She actually asked me if I "use big words to intimidate people."
Right before I die of Alzheimer's, that will be the last memory I forget.
Here, I don't have that problem. Y'all are even smarter than I am. It's like breathing air when I've been trapped underwater, and I'm eager to learn from you.
But instead, I can't ask questions at physics or astronomy because I'm dismissed with a handwave as just a smartmouth smartass pot-smoking prostie who wastes her priceless Jedi powers by sleeping till 3 pm, laying around naked, and lighting joints with Force Lightning from her finger.
For about two weeks, I've wanted desperately to ask about  the L parameter in one of the versions of the Schrodinger equation: What does length have to do with it? In 4 dimensions, it's a point event! L is always the Planck length!
Yeah, I get enthusiastic and joyful about different things than normal people. So shoot me. But I gave up on ever finding out.
"No, hell, we don't have to take her astrophysics questions seriously!"
Your post is like the old white southern judge getting mad at the black guy who dared to assert that the law isn't impartial: a lotta indignant  "HARRUMPH!" but no dignified TRUTH.
Science is supposed to be above that.
Your disingenuous detraction doesn't impress me.

@Dcleve Physics is pretty open to physics questions at any level.  I do agree that a lot of questions get downvoted/closed there, but that's more due to some "veterans" quality standards, not because the question isnt PhD/masters level.  I dont have masters/PhD, or even physics degree, and I was able to participate without issue.
